# How to integrate Vue.js with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, vue.js, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to develop an application in ASP.NET MVC Core with Vue.js views.

How should I setup my application to work with both technologies?

Regards

Comment: use ASP.NET Core SPA Templates: http://vsixgallery.com/extension/4336beed-a389-4f86-9138-40d258e78ccf/

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a beginner level approach and to develop a Vue spa application, I suggest you on using following boilerplate.

> 1. npm install -g yo generator-aspnetcore-spa
> 2. cd some-empty-directory
> 3. yo aspnetcore-spa

Select vue from the list

Answer (score 0):

Vue supports both SPA and Non-SPA application development. https://github.com/mrityunjaya-kumar/AspNetCore-Vue-Starter provides a simple way of using ASP.NET core 2 + VueJS + Bootstrap-Vue for beginners.

For beginners, if you are interested in pure javascript development start with vue Javascript libraries only and then proceed with SPA app.

For SPA app, https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter is a nice starting point.